# problem involving polynomial ring over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

[image]

So far, I have the following:

[image]

Could someone show me why $h \mid x^q -x$ and also why $h$ has a root $b$ in $F$? I can figure out the rest. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: If $h|x^{q}-x$, it follows that a root $b$ of $h$ is a root of $x^{q}-x$, i.e. $b^{q} - b = 0$, so $b^{q} = b$. What, therefore, is true of $b$?

Comment: So... was $a$ used elsewhere in the problem statement or was it just thrown in there as decoration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F_q$ be shorthand for the quotient.

Since $F_q\setminus\{0\}$ is a finite multiplicative group of order $q-1$, $a^{q-1}=1$ for all $a\in F_q\setminus \{0\}$. Then also, $a^q=a$ for these elements, and $0^q=0$ already.

So look: whatever element $\bar{x}$ happens to be in the field, $\bar{x}^q-\bar{x}=\bar{0}$, meaning that $\overline{x^q-q}=\bar{0}$, hence $x^q-x\in (h)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I should have seen that. Very silly of me. Thank you for your help @rschwieb

Comment: Dear @Sarah No problem! Glad the foothold I gave got you on your way :)